# DRF update on none

Tags: django-rest-framework

I understand this is basic but I'm pulling hair.
In my previous projects, this always were able to update. I pulled up past projects to compare but this isn't updating and keeps asking for values. I'd like it to take values if not null and keep previous existing values. 
also tried `partial=True` but that gives Blank in my fields which isn't what I want.

```
class UserRetrieveUpdateAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = { 'user': request.user }
        serializer = self.serializer(request.user, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            self.perform_update(serializer)
            instance = serializer.instance
            self.clear_cache(request.user)
```

So None should be whatever previously was

`print (serializer) #<User: demo@email.com>, data={'first_name': None, 'last_name': 'stupid', 'email': None, 'password': None}`

Serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','email','password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data.get('username'),
            email=validated_data.get('email')
        )
        user.save()
        return user

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        first_name = validated_data.pop('first_name', None)
        print (first_name)

        for key, value in validated_data.items():
            if value != None:
                setattr(instance, key, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: Are you PUTting or PATCHing in your request?

Comment: Are you using a different version of rest framework in this project than your previous projects?  i.e. 3.8.0 has breaking changes https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#380